# Passing array and index within `for` loop and `setTimeout()`

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, settimeout, self-invoking-function

I would like to execute a click on `templates[i]` within `setTimeout` within a `for` loop

```
for(var i=0; i<templates.length; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        (function(){
            templates[i].click();
        }(i, templates));
    }, 200);
}
```

I get the error `templates[i]` is undefined.

However, something like this works fine:

```
for(var i=0; i<templates.length; i++){  
    setTimeout(function(){
        (function(){
            console.log(templates_arr+templates)
        }(templates_arr, templates));
    }, 200);
}
```

Can anybody shed some light onto why this is like this and how I can pass the array and index properly?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: it is because by the time the IIFE is executed the value of `i` is changed to `templates.length`

Comment: It's a scoping issue. Once the timeout fires, `i` is no longer in scope.

Comment: So it should be `for (var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
  (function(i, templates) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      templates[i].click();
    }, 200);
  }(i, templates));
}
`

Comment: Thanks guys. Solves by passing a value which would definitely be the same at that moment in time.

`for(var i=0; i<templates.length; i++){
 setTimeout(function(){
  (function(){
   templates[templates_arr.length].click();
  }(templates));
 }, 200);
 
 setTimeout(function(){
  (function(){
   templates_arr.push(htmlDecode(mainwindow.document.getElementById('XmlFrame').contentDocument.getElementById('id_1').innerHTML));
  }(templates_arr, templates));
 }, 200);
}`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: yours is the elegant solution. I find the following easier to read, does it have any drawbacks? `for (var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
 var func = function(template) {
  setTimeout(function() { 
   template.click(); 
  }, 200); };
 func(templates[i]); 
}`

Comment: @JohannesJander you are creating multiple function instances, you can solve it by using `var func = function(template) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    template.click();
  }, 200);
};
for (var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
  func(templates[i]);
}
`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Thanks, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be

```
for(var i=0; i<templates.length; i++){
   (function(i,templates){
       setTimeout(function(){
            templates[i].click();
       }, 200);
   })(i, templates);

}
```